# bash: Wait for process substitution subshell to finish

Tags: bash, xargs, process-substitution

How can bash wait for the subshell used in process substitution to finish in the following construct?  (This is of course simplified from the real for loop and subshell which I am using, but it illustrates the intent well.)

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "$i"
done > >(xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Subshell: $0"')
echo "Finished"
```

Prints:

```
Finished
Subshell: 1
Subshell: 2
Subshell: 3
```

Instead of:

```
Subshell: 1
Subshell: 2
Subshell: 3
Finished
```

How can I make bash wait for those subshells to complete?

**UPDATE**

The reason for using process substitution is that I'm wanting to use file descriptors to control what is printed to the screen and what is sent to the process.  Here is a fuller version of what I'm doing:

```
for myFile in file1 file2 file3; do
    echo "Downloading $myFile"     # Should print to terminal
    scp -q $user@$host:$myFile ./  # Might take a long time
    echo "$myFile" >&3             # Should go to process substitution
done 3> >(xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Processing: $0"')
echo "Finished"
```

Prints:

```
Downloading file1
Downloading file2
Downloading file3
Finished
Processing: file1
Processing: file2
Processing: file3
```

Processing each may take much longer than the transfer.  The file transfers should be sequential since bandwidth is the limiting factor.  I would like to start processing each file after it is received without waiting for all of them to transfer.  The processing can be done in parallel, but only a with a limited number of instances (due to limited memory/CPU).  So if the fifth file just finished transferring but only the second file has finished processing, the third and fourth files should complete processing before the fifth file is processed.  Meanwhile the sixth file should start transferring.

Comment: I don't think there's a way. Why are you using process substitution instead of just piping?

Comment: This *is* possible, but only with very new versions of bash. Which release are we targeting here?

Comment: I'm using bash 4.1

Comment: 4.1 won't cut it.

Comment: I'll update the post for the reasoning behind the process substitution, although I may wind up with just piping.

Comment: If that's what you're doing, why the `xargs bash -c`? `3> >(while IFS= read -r name; do sleep 1; echo "Processing: $name"; done)` would be far less overhead. That said, there are some other changes I'd make for the sake of correctness (fixing up the quoting, using NUL delimiters for the stream of completed names, etc).

Comment: That said, this looks to me like a scenario where just inverting which piece is done in a subprocess would solve your problem.

Comment: The reason for xargs is to allow a controlled number of subprocesses to run simultaneously.  E.g. I may want 2 or 4 or only 1 instance of the bash script to execute in parallel.

Comment: BTW, as another aside, status content printed to the terminal is *exactly* what stderr is for ("diagnostic" content is the word in the POSIX spec, and status updates are diagnostic). So you could certainly use a pipeline.

Comment: If you want multiple parallel downloads, that's even more reason to put the download side into the subprocess. Right now, you have only one download process, but potentially (if you used `xargs -P`) multiple status-printing processes.

Comment: The downloads should be sequential.  Bandwidth is fairly limited and I would like to complete a transfer before starting another.

Comment: ...then I don't understand the reasoning behind use of `xargs` here.

Comment: I'm thinking xargs in this construct allows each transferred file to be buffered for processing.  Say I'm transferring 20 files and each transfer is 1 minute.  The transfer should be complete in 20 minutes.  Then assume that processing each file takes between 10 seconds and 5 minutes.  I don't want to wait for all the files to transfer before I start processing, and I can't risk processing too many in parallel or I'll exhaust my resources.

Comment: Ahh. Just a `while read` loop should suffice -- no need for `xargs` spawning a whole new shell -- but it makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Bash 4.4 lets you collect the PID of a process substitution with `$!`, so you can actually use `wait`, just as you would for a background process:

```
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.[0123])
  echo "ERROR: Bash 4.4 required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

# open the process substitution
exec {ps_out_fd}> >(xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Subshell: $0"'); ps_out_pid=$!

for i in {1..3}; do
  echo "$i"
done >&$ps_out_fd

# close the process substitution
exec {ps_out_fd}>&-

# ...and wait for it to exit.
wait "$ps_out_pid"
```

---

Beyond that, consider `flock`-style locking -- though beware of races:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
  echo "$i"
done > >(flock -x my.lock xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Subshell: $0"')

# this is only safe if the "for" loop can't exit without the process substitution reading
# something (and thus signalling that it successfully started up)

flock -x my.lock echo "Lock grabbed; the subshell has finished"
```

---

That said, given your *actual* use case, what you want should presumably look more like:

```
download() {
  for arg; do
    scp -q $user@$host:$myFile ./ || (( retval |= $? ))
  done
  exit "$retval"
}
export -f download

printf '%s\0' file1 file2 file3 |
  xargs -0 -P2 -n1 bash -c 'download "$@"' _
```

Comment: Maybe this is due to a bash version discrepancy, but if I wait on a child process created in a process substitution (making the child report $$, instead of using $!), I get "pid 12345 is not a child of this shell". Tested with: `: <(echo "$$" > childpid; sleep 10; echo childdone >&2); sleep 1; wait "$(cat childpid)"`. Version: 4.3.48(1)-release

Comment: @init_js, yes, it strictly needs to be version 4.4 for process substitution PIDs to be `wait`able.

Answer (score 3):

you could have the subshell create a file that the main shell waits for.

```
tempfile=/tmp/finished.$$
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "$i"
done > >(xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Subshell: $0"'; touch $tempfile)
while ! test -f $tempfile; do sleep 1; done
rm $tempfile
echo "Finished"
```

Comment: Could this work with the loop construct though?  If each iteration of the loop touches the same file, the second and third iterations would be touching the same file and the main script would stop waiting after the first iteration completes.

Comment: @RustyLemur, the `touch` only runs after `xargs` exited, meaning the all iterations are done.

Comment: Oh I see.  That's handy!

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash `coproc` to hold a read-able filedescriptor to be closed when all process' children die:

```
coproc read                  # previously: `coproc cat`, see comments
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "$i"
done > >(xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Subshell: $0"')
exec {COPROC[1]}>&-          # close my writing side
read -u ${COPROC[0]}         # will wait until all potential writers (ie process children) end
echo "Finished"
```

Comment: You don't need `eval` with bash 4.1 -- `exec {var_holding_fd}>&-` will close the FD named in the variable `var_holding_fd`.

Comment: What is the significance of `cat` in `coproc cat`?  Could any string be used there?

Comment: Afaik unfortunately it's not possible to create a "naked" pipe (as in `pipe(2)` syscall) which would perfectly serve for this purpose. The closest (while simple) I found is `coproc cat` (as `cat` will exit when its reading side is closed), see also https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo -- hm that said, `coproc read` will also work (while avoid exec'ing an external command) :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is to be run on a system where there is an attacker you should not use a temp file name that can be guessed. So based on @Barmar's solution here is one that avoids that:

```
tempfile="`tempfile`"
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "$i"
done > >(xargs -n1 bash -c 'sleep 1; echo "Subshell: $0"'; rm "$tempfile")
while test -f "$tempfile"; do sleep 1; done
echo "Finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Something like this works because the internal bash executions are a subprocess of the main process, the wait causes the process to wait until everything is finished before printing.

```
for i in {1..3}
do
    bash -c "sleep 1; echo Subshell: $i"  &
done
wait
echo "Finished"
```

Unix and derivatives (Linux) have the ability to wait for child (sub) processes but not grandchild processes such as occurred in your original.  Some would consider the polling solution where you go back and check for completion to be vulgar since it does not use this mechanism.

The solution where the xargs PID was captured was not vulgar, just too complicated.